# How to return Enum if matches with given String

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enums, enumeration, enumerate

I have Enum class as given below

```
public enum AlgorithmEnum {

    SHA512("RSA", "SHA512", 1), SHA1("RSA", "SHA1", 1), SHA384("RSA", "SHA384", 1);

    private String keyAlgorithm;
    private String hashAlgorithm;
    private Integer key;

    private AlgorithmEnum(String keyAlgorithm, String hashAlgorithm, Integer key) {
        this.keyAlgorithm = keyAlgorithm;
        this.hashAlgorithm = hashAlgorithm;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKeyAlgorithm() {
        return keyAlgorithm;
    }

    public void setKeyAlgorithm(String keyAlgorithm) {
        this.keyAlgorithm = keyAlgorithm;
    }

    public String getHashAlgorithm() {
        return hashAlgorithm;
    }

    public void setHashAlgorithm(String hashAlgorithm) {
        this.hashAlgorithm = hashAlgorithm;
    }

    public Integer getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Integer key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

I need to have method something like below which takes input as string and returns Enum

```
public AlgorithmEnum getAlgorithm(String algorithm){
        //returns AlgorithmEnum object
    }
```

I would call above method by passing "SHA512withRSA" as input for getAlgorithm method.

I need help in implementing the getAlgorithm method.

Comment: add a getter and compare them

Comment: There is no enum constant defined with `SHA512withRSA`. How are you expecting it to return a value? Would all strings have a syntax ending `withRSA`?

Comment: Please add code you tried to do and failed before you actually posted the question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like:

```
public static AlgorithmEnum getAlgorithm(final String algorithm)
        throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        for (final AlgorithmEnum algorithmEnum : AlgorithmEnum.values())
        {
            if (algorithm.equalsIgnoreCase(String.format("%swith%s", algorithmEnum.getHashAlgorithm(), algorithmEnum.getKeyAlgorithm())))
            {
                return algorithmEnum;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown algorithm: " + algorithm);
    }
```

However, I will not suggest to use this approach. Instead use 2 different arguments instead of a single String.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all string values passed to your method `getAlgorithm()` end with `withRSA` you could use the following to fetch the enum values :

```
public AlgorithmEnum getAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
    return AlgorithmEnum.valueOf(algorithm.substring(0, algorithm.indexOf("withRSA")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the given `String` contains a value that matches one of the `enum` attributes with some `if` statements:

```
public AlgorithmEnum getAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
    if (algorithm.contains("SHA1")) {
        return SHA1;
    } else if (algorithm.contains("SHA512")) {
        return SHA512;
    } else if (algorithm.contains("SHA384")) {
        return SHA384;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Please note that this will match `String`s like `"SHA512withoutRSA"`, too...

Maybe a method like

```
public AlgorithmEnum getAlgorithm(String keyAlgorithm, String hashAlgorithm)
```

would be better. However, you would have to provide two parameters then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving you an example of how I did on similar cases, you can easily adapt it to your needs:

```
private static Map<Integer, YourEnum> valuesById = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<String, YourEnum> valuesByCode = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        Arrays.stream(YourEnum.values()).forEach(value -> valuesById.put(value.reasonId, value));
        Arrays.stream(YourEnum.values()).forEach(value -> valuesByCode.put(value.reasonCode, value));
    }


    public static YourEnum getByReasonId(int endReason) {
        return valuesById.get(endReason);
    }
```